# Not able to Save the POST data contents of an XFDF form

Tags: java, spring, pdf, itext, acrobat

We are **Not** able to Save the POST data contents from an XFDF form. The POST event is triggered using a button inside the PDF.

We are using **Java + SPRING** on server side.

**EXCEPTION:**

`java.io.IOException: Expected > for tag: <{1}/> near line 1, column 13`

Observed the same error in itext demo page too! Here it is: http://itextpdf.com:8180/book/xfdf

Please help us finding the solution.

[**MORE DETAILS**]

The error is reproducible in the iText demo page itself. 
Url:http://itextpdf.com:8180/book/xfdf 
We can notice it in the ajax response part after submitting the form.

By the way, here is the input, ouput and source code in our app.

**HTTP POST INPUT DATA:**

```
%FDF-1.2
1 0 obj
<</FDF<</F<</Type/Filespec/F(http///localhost/8081/triplefin/document/download/4)/UF(http///localhost/8081/triplefin/document/download/4)>>/Fields[<</T(pat_name)/V(sample)>><</T(member_number)>><</T(p_add)>><</T(p_city)>><</T(p_state)>><</T(p_zip)>><</T(pat_phone)>><</T(pat_dob)>><</T(doc_name)/V(provider1)>><</T(doc_add)/V(7/15 krishna nagar)>><</T(doc_city)/V(coimbatore)>><</T(doc_state)/V(641041)>><</T(doc_zip)>><</T(doc_phone)/V(1232131)>><</T(doc_fax)/V(023423423)>><</T(specialty)>><</T(npi_number)>><</T(drug)>><</T(drug_dosage)>><</T(rx_direction)>><</T(Diagnosis)>><</T(pat_start_date)>><</T(alternatives_used)>><</T(non_formulary_reason)>><</T(addi_treatment)>><</T(doc_signature)>><</T(doc_sig_date)>>]>>>>
endobj

trailer
<</Root 1 0 R>>
%%EO
```

**DETAILED EXCEPTION MESSAGE:**

```
java.io.IOException: Expected > for tag: <{1}/> near line 1, column 13
    at com.itextpdf.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.throwException(SimpleXMLParser.java:594)
    at com.itextpdf.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.go(SimpleXMLParser.java:353)
    at com.itextpdf.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.parse(SimpleXMLParser.java:607)
    at com.itextpdf.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.parse(SimpleXMLParser.java:682)
    at com.itextpdf.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.parse(SimpleXMLParser.java:648)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.XfdfReader.<init>(XfdfReader.java:113)
```

**SOURCE CODE:**

```
public void savePostDataToPdf(String pdfFileAbsolutePathString, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{

    XfdfReader xfdfReaderObject = new XfdfReader(request.getInputStream()); //ERROR IS HERE!

}
```

Comment: I just executed the sample code as in the documentation (http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=172) and I encountered no exceptions. Could you show us your entire code or check where your code differs from the sample?

Comment: I don't see anything you're doing wrong. What do you mean "the problem is reproducible with the demo page"? I entered info in that page and submitted it and I got the expected result. I also rebuilt that pdf to submit the data to a local tomcat and got no exception. Could you provide your pdf?

Comment: Please see the AJAX response in the page: http://itextpdf.com:8180/book/xfdf  (After clicking of POST button).

Comment: We got the exact same error. In our case it happened when someone typed in a '<' character in the webform, which was somehow not escaped when filling the xfdf. We use itext-4.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're posting FDF data but using the XFDF reader. FDF and XFDF are different formats, and the XFDF reader is treating it as an XML string and throwing an error about unclosed tags.

If you're just providing FDF files, you'd want something like:

```
FdfReader fdfReaderObject = new FdfReader(request.getInputStream());
```