# Exception thrown parsing the PDF post data using iText

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to implement the submit form & parse the submitted data in the back-end as provided in the [this link](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=172), but in vain. I am facing a weird error (please see below) which I am not able to find a solution and any help in solving this problem is appreciated.

**Problem**

I fill up the form in the PDF and hit the submit button (similar to http://itextpdf.com:8180/book/xfdf) when I read the post data in the server, I get the below IOException.

**Exception**

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ITextServlet] in context with path
[/IText_WEB_Project] threw exception
java.io.IOException: Expected > for tag: <{1}/> near line 1, column 13
```

Thanks in advance.

**Note**

I have also did a quick search over google but I couldn't find an appropriate solution for the above problem, I have also contact the iText mailing list and waiting for some positive response.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate from this question asked yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986163/not-able-to-save-the-post-data-contents-of-an-xfdf-form

Comment: In Below post I didn't find answer.. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986163/not-able-to-save-the-post-data-contents-of-an-xfdf-form

Answer (score 0):

We also got the error java.io.IOException: Expected > for tag: <{1}/>. In our application it happened when someone typed in a '<' character in the webform, which was somehow not escaped when filling the xfdf. We use itext-4.2.1.